# Add Maven repository to Tomcat's classpath

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I'm working with Maven and Tomcat. Some of the web applications I have to deploy use a lot of dependencies that are marked as "provided" in Maven. One example of these dependencies is *spring-context*.

So, when I package the project, those dependencies are not included in the lib folder of the WAR file. 
Because of this, I'm getting

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
```

I can't change the scope of the dependencies, and if possible, I don't want to include the dependencies JARs in the WAR file.

How can I add the Maven repository as a classpath to Tomcat, so it can resolve all the "provided" dependencies? Without copying the JARs to Tomcat's lib folder.

I tried the *shared.loader* property in *catalina.properties*, but it doesn't work recursively: I have to add each JAR path to the property's value.

Comment: `mvn -Dmdep.outputFile=FILE  dependency:build-classpath` will write the fully qualified pathnames of all dependencies to `FILE`, in a format suitable for `java -cp`. It should be an easy matter for you to  decompose this string and copy the dependencies into Tomcat's shared lib directory. **BEWARE**, however, that you will be in for classpath hell if you do this (which is why I didn't post as an answer; it would be rightly downvoted to oblivion).

Answer (score 3):

A dependency is marked as provided when the app server or container already has it, and you don't have to put it in the war. This is the case i.e. for the servlets jar, but not for the spring-context. I think the better solution would be to mark this dependencies as "compile" instead of "provided".

Comment: Yes, that would be the best option. The problem is that I cannot change the scope of the dependencies. Legacy projects are a pain in the ass.

Comment: You can repackage and redeploy the project but you cannot change the scope of the dependencies because they are "legacy" projects ? Now i'm curious...

Comment: Probably I misused the term "legacy". It is not that I "can't". It's that due some weird team requirements I'm "not allowed" to change the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options here. Like @Andres said, you either add the JARs in the WAR or you add them to the classpath of Tomcat (ie lib folder).

While the concept of having a *Maven-aware* classloader is interesting, imagine all the possible   jar version conflicts that could occur. **War A** having a provided dependency on **Lib v1.0.1** and **War B** having a provided dependency on **Lib v2.1.0**, with Tomcat silently resolving these...